# Display comma between each in foreach in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

In the following code in the foreach for Themes, how would I display the theme with a comma and a space.  For example "Theme, Theme2, Theme 3"?  Also how would I just display the one Theme if the count is not less then 1?

```
<tbody>
        @foreach (var piece in PieceService.Pieces)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@piece.Id</td>
                <td>@piece.Title</td>
                <td>@piece.Publisher.Name</td>
                <td>@piece.Parts.Count()</td>
                <td>@foreach (var theme in @piece.Themes)
                    {
                        @if (@piece.Themes.Count() > 1)
                        {
                            theme.Title, ;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            theme.Title;
                        }
                    }
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="(() => ShowPiece(piece.Id))">Show</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="(() => EditPiece(piece.Id))">Edit</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="(() => DeletePiece(piece.Id))">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this statement to achieve the result you want

```
<td>
    @string.Join(", ", @piece.Themes.Select(x=> x.Title).ToArray())
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

C# has a `.Last()` method that you could use:

```
@{
    Piece LastItem = PieceService.Pieces.Last();
    foreach (var item in PieceService)
    {
        @item.Name
        @if (item != LastItem)
        {
            @(", ")
        }
    }
}
```

I provide this answer as an alternative to the other pure string-based answers because it still leaves room for adding html formatting, including `div` objects with separate `onclick` events, etc. later if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Write a method in the code block

```
@code {
    private string GetThemes(xxx themes)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        themes.ForEach(item => sb.Append($"{item.Title}, "));
        return sb.ToString().Trim().Trim(',');
    }
}
```

and then:

```
<td>
  @this.GetThemes(@piece.Themes)
</td>
```

You don't have to write everything inline.

Answer (score 0):

A way using `System.Linq`.
Replace your foreach loop with :

```
@(piece.Themes.Select(a => a.Title).Aggregate((a,b) => a+","+b ))
```